# Modify only part of the state in a react-redux app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

As a practice exercise, I am writing a react-redux calculator app. My app's state is defined as:

```
const initialState = {
  operator1: "",  //first operand
  operator2: "",  //second operand
  currentOp: "",  // +, -, *, /
  display:"",     //the current calculator display
  currentOperator:1  //which operand is being entered right now
}
```

currentOp holds the symbol of the operation currently being performed by the calculator, which, when entering the first operand, is empty. Therefore, when my calculator's numbers are pressed, I need to update the display, but without loosing my other state properties.  I wrote my reducer like this:

```
import {NUMBER_PRESSED,OPERATION_PRESSED,EQUAL_PRESSED} from './actions';

const mainReducer = (state ={},action) =>
{
console.log("reducer called!");
console.log(action);
const newState = {};

//copy the operators to the new state. Only one will be changed. (Is this really necessary?)
newState.operator1 = state.operator1;
newState.operator2 = state.operator2;

switch(action.type)
{

    case NUMBER_PRESSED:
        if (state.currentOperator===1)
        {
            newState.operator1 = state.operator1 + action.payload;
            newState.display= newState.operator1;
        }
        if(state.currentOperator===2)
        {
            newState.operator2 = state.operator2 + action.payload;
            newState.display= newState.operator2;
        }

        //set the other properties of the state (Is this really necessary?)
        newState.currentOperator = state.currentOperator;
        newState.currentOp = state.currentOp;

        console.log("The new state is:");
        console.log(newState);
        return newState;

    case OPERATION_PRESSED:

        break;
    case EQUAL_PRESSED:

        break;

    default:
        return state;
}
}

export default mainReducer;
```

Please note that I have not yet implemented the calculation operations, just updating the display. If I change the state variable directly, the calculator component does not update. Understandable, and this is expected behavior explained in the docs. However, it seems that I need to manually copy the entire state into a new variable so that it is preserved the next state (notice the "Is this really necessary?" comments in the code.
I have no problem copying all the app's state and returning an entirely new state object, but what happens on bigger applications with huge state trees? How is this managed? Is there a way to modify only part of the state in redux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use things like the spread operator to duplicate entire objects without having to set each one manually:

```
const x = state.someArray.slice();
x[1] = "potato";
return {...state, someArray:x}
```

But to answer your concern, yes you do have to make an entire new duplicate of the state when changing it. It's not usually an issue, and doesn't take much time. If your state tree is HUGE then the solution should be splitting up that tree into separate reducers, that way you only have to duplicate and replace parts of the tree when changing the state.

Comment: But won't all reducers still need to copy the entire state tree, even whey they are only using a part of it? What about memory usage? If I have a huge state tree, won't copying it duplicate memory usage while it is in scope?

Comment: Your store tree should never be particularly huge, and it shouldn't contain memory intense stuff like hundreds of thousands of results from a search. If you ever get to a point where changing the state is slow because your store has huge amounts of data, then the problem isn't the duplication of the tree, it's that you have far too much data client side and you've got stuff in the store that you shouldn't.

Comment: Basically if you get to a point where duplication of your Redux store is the problem, then duplication of your Redux store ISN'T the problem lol. And you should revisit what you're storing in there. Javascript browser engines are quite powerful nowadays so if your store is appropriate then copying it shouldn't be slow and it's memory footprint should be very small.

Comment: How would one go about handling a client side app that displays hundreds of records then, if they aren't meant to be stored in the state tree?

Comment: It depends on the use case, but ideally you don't store much data client side at all, it's better to paginate your data. Show it in small groups, and have them request a new set as they want it, swapping out the current set for the new one so they're only ever viewing a slice of it. But even like 1,000 JSON objects would probably only be a few hundred KB, depending on how big each object was. That won't take much time/memory to duplicate. If you start storing more then that, the issue isn't how to manage Redux tree duplication, it's how to stop storing so much stuff client side.

Answer (score 0):

1: If your state is **decoupling** you should use [combineReducers](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers) *It is recursion*

2: If not, you should use [es6 destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

3: What's more, you should consider about your state structure.(depends on your reducer code, i suggest...)

base on 2, for example

```
const mainReducer = (state = {},action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
    case NUMBER_PRESSED:
        if (state.currentOperator===1) return {
           ...state,
           operator1: state.operator1 + action.payload,
           display: 'operator1'
        }
        if(state.currentOperator===2) return {
           ...state,
           operator2: state.operator2 + action.payload,
           display: 'operator2'
        }
        return state
    default: return state;
    }
}
```

If it's still huge with correctly program design....Product Design?